# Which packaging is appropriate for a Python Application?

Tags: python, windows, packaging

I mean, from the user perspective, which packaging/distribution format should be appropriate? The preferred result would be that the user would only need to *"double-click"* to run the application, specially because I'm targeting **mainly** Windows users. Sadly I've observed that the Python Interpreter Installer for Windows does not associate neither `*.py` nor `EGG` files to be opened with it.

I had already read a lot of documentation about Distutils/Setuptools but it's very confusing because the process changes slightly depending on the Python version, furthermore the only 2 libraries that my application use are not available on the PyPi (Which are the PyQT4 wrapper and NumPy). So the benefits of using any of those packaging tools are almost none.

Maybe I should just distribute the application zipped and provide a `BAT` script?

Another preference is that the application should be portable (no installation required), maybe I'm asking too much?

Comment: Have you looked into any of the options for creating a single executable, or do you particularly *want* to distribute the source code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Note that I said **mainly** Windows users, but not limited to. So, while creating a Windows Executable would be fine it will enclose the application to Windows, unless I create alternate distribution packages for other OSes, which I would like to avoid

Comment: Then have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9035424/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that's what I was looking for, I saw PyInstaller listed on a Wiki but I thought it was just another tool to create Windows Installers