# run python script on other linux machine without internet access and pip

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I have ready script on my laptop, and script use external python libs witch I installed on my laptop, how to move script with packages on other linux machine? Machine working without internet and pip package

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you can try to install pip in your home directory in the remote machine? Something like pyenv or so?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035424/cross-platform-alternative-to-py2exe) where [pyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) is recommended.